# Scratch - broadcast touching sensors

Tags: cs50, mit-scratch

I've come back to this project with a little more resolve to fix my old bug.

See: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/75999804/

**Problem Description**
When using the "touching colour" sensing block it works properly (spite bounces and can jump properly). I wanted to make my own touching sensors for more control (with different objects, different colours etc). However, my touching sensors do not work with the same behaviour and I cannot understand why (the sprite no longer "bounces" and "jumps" properly).

**See Problem in Action**
Compare behaviour
- See comment in the scmpoo sprite for the problem area
- Below the forever loop swap the following "touchingFoot = true" with "touching colour [brown]"
They should have the same action but you'll see the difference in behaviour

TouchingFoot (and all the sensors) are declared under game and are a continuous loop broadcasting (to sense contact with desired objects).

Hope that someone can help out, I'm really scratching my head here (no pun intended).

-- Further Detail - 2018/04/25

I wanted to try to use sensors to avoid very long if statements. (This could happen if I make it a side-scroller with many platforms). Proving tricky to find the right logic. (I see the problem is that when the sprite is touching just one one of the blocks the requests from the other blocks (not_touching) is competitng with the block loop it is touching.

I was looking for a way to perform the checks within the platform spite itself. (To make the if statements more manageable).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean - I just went to your project and they seem to work the same way. Could you please provide some screenshots of the *exact* code that's giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
I can't get your project to work properly, but the following will make it behave like the "touching colour [brown]" block.

Change:

[image: Script to change]

To:

[image: Script changed]

Why:

Your previous script checks for collisions with one sprite and sets the variable, but if it is not touching the second sprite it gets reset to "false". This means it will only trigger if your sheep is touching all of the sprites.

Edit:
This is if you want to do it in the platforms.
Change the script in your 'game' sprite to:

[image: Script changed]

Also change the sprit in your platforms to:

[image]

This resets the sensors. Then it broadcasts 'collisiondetect', and the sensors are set to 'true' if there is a collision. Done in a remix.

Comment: Thank you, I had wanted to try to use sensors to achieve something similar to avoid very very long if statements. (This could happen if I make it a side-scroller with many platforms). Proving tricky to find the right logic but I do appreciate your reply.

I had in my mind a way to include the checks within the platform spite itself. (To make the if statements more manageable).

Comment: You can include the checks in the platform sprite. Wait, I'll show you soon.

Comment: Change the script in your 'game' sprite to [this](http://i64.tinypic.com/2hwmatw.png), and the sprit in your platforms to [this](http://i65.tinypic.com/24n0c21.png). This resets the sensors. Then it broadcasts 'collisiondetect', and the sensors are set to 'true' if there is a collision. Done in a remix.